# pandas split a row to two or more column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe sample is below and I want to split the column and make a whole new column of it's data.

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|           col a                                     |         col b                                  |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|[{'parameter': 'o3', 'value': 191, 'lastUpdate...    |{'latitude': 39.2133, 'longitude': 117.1837}    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want output like this

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|parametes | value | lastupdate |  latitude |longitude |
|----------|-------|------------|-----------|----------|
|o3        | 191   | vlaue1     | 39.21     | 117.18   |
|a3        | 205   | vlaue2     | 39.22     | 117.11   |
|r4        | 456   | vlaue3     | 39.23     | 117.12   |
|y5        | 789   | vlaue4     | 39.24     | 117.13   |
|r4        | 305   | vlaue5     | 39.25     | 117.14   |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
df_col_a = df['col a'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Same way you can split the other column as well

```
df_col_b = df['col b'].apply(pd.Series)
```

now can you concat the two dataframes

```
result_df = pd.concat([df_col_a,df_col_b],axis=1)
```

Comment: bro this work for `col_b` but not for `col a`. because the `col a' data is in this form [{  }]

Comment: since col a is list, you can explode the list. df.explode('col a') and convert it columns using the steps above